# Can we make adfs to check roles too for authentication with username and password?

Tags: authentication, ldap, openid-connect, adfs3.0

I am working on ADFS services for SSO project and was curious to know if we can make adfs to also check roles for authentication not just username and password.
So it will be like for authentication check username password and roles and if user belong to a particular role, he should be authenticated else not.
And I am not sure about it because it should fall under authorization instead of authentication but curious to know if it can be achieved.

I am using OpenIdConnect Protocol and LDAP for user information storage.

Edit 1:
Here an scenario for the problem:

```
 site A(only Admin role user can access): 
      user provides UserName/Password and user do not belong to admin role(authentication failed and login failed to application). 

 Site B (Any User can access) : 
      user provides UserName/Password and user do not belong to admin role(authenticated and logged in to application).
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can configure ADFS for claims rules and for access policy.

So you can say e.g. that only members with role x can access the application. Or that members with role y can't.

Comment: it's not about the application access, its more about to not even let authenticated at the first hand.
Here an example :
site A(only Admin role user can access):
      user provides UserName/Password and user do not belong to admin role(authentication failed and login failed to application).

Site B (Any User can access) :
     user provides UserName/Password and user do not belong to admin 
 role(authenticated and logged in to application).

Comment: Yes - ADFS asks you to authenticate and then checks access as above. There is no way to change this.